# Swift - scroll bar swipe function

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uiscrollview

This is Alibaba.com's ios application. In the app, if I swipe left the bar will scroll left and reveal more clickable options. My question is, how is this made?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: it is just a scroll view. I think this can help you： https://github.com/hrscy/TodayNews

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

**1.** Firstly make a `.xib` file, name it to whatever you want, I named mine to unnamedView, then add the labels and imageViews.

**2.** Then create UnnamedView class file like this and add all labels and images

```
class unnamedView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var firstButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var firstLabel: UILabel!
}
```

**3.** Then create a array for the UnnamedView in the main view controller.

```
let unnamed = ["title1":"textTitleToLabel","image1":"nameOfImage"]

var unnamedArray = [Dictionary<String,String>]()
```

**4.** Then I added the scroll view to the main view controller

```
@IBOutlet weak var unnamedScrollView: UIScrollView!
```

**5.** Inside viewDidLoad() add following

```
unnamedArray = [unnamed]
        unnamedScrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
        unnamedScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: unnamedScrollView.bounds.width * CGFloat(unnamedArray.count), height: 100)
        unnamedScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        unnamedScrollView.delegate = self
        loadUnnamed()
```

**6.** And lastly added following bellow the viewDidLoad

```
func loadCategories() {

        for (index, category) in categoriesArray.enumerated() {
            if let unnamedView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("unnamedView", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? unnamedView {

                unnamedView.firstImage.image = UIImage(named: category["image1"]!)
                unnamedView.firstLabel.text = category["title1"]

                unnamedView.firstButton.tag = index
                unnamedView.firstButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.gotoCategory(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

                unnamedScrollView.addSubview(unnamedView)
                unnamedView.frame.size.width = self.view.bounds.size.width
                unnamedView.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(index) * self.view.bounds.size.width

            }
        }
    }

    func gotoCategory (sender:UIButton) {
        print("The user wants to buy feature \(sender.tag)")
        let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let newViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tableView")
        self.present(newViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

And also, if you'd like to add page control dots, simply to this.

```
@IBOutlet weak var featurePageControl: UIPageControl!

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width
    featurePageControl.currentPage = Int(page)
}
```